# table cell with border-image

Tags: html, css

I want to add border image to table cells, but it doesn't work ...or I'm doing sth wrong... Border width is visible, but image is missing. My jsFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2y3xqq0q/), code:

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,  .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
    border: 0; /* reset */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 27px;
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 fill repeat;
}
```

Border-image code is generated with [border-image.com](http://border-image.com)

Any ideas? Or border-image is simply unsupported for tables?

Comment: It's supported but it's not clear exactly what this is supposed to look like. - https://jsfiddle.net/2y3xqq0q/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've included bootstrap.min.css which is overriding your CSS.

Try this fiddle instead: https://jsfiddle.net/6025vyn9/

**Edit:** To clarify, `border-image` applies to tables (the outside of the table) but doesn't apply to internal table elements when `border-collapse` is `collapse`: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image-source

Comment: Thanks, but same here: why when I'm trying to collapse borders, images disappear like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6025vyn9/1/)?

Comment: By collapsing the borders you're telling the browser not to render the borders at all.  If you're trying to put a border just around the outside of the table then this should work (i.e. just apply the styles to the table): https://jsfiddle.net/3z07q8q0/

Comment: Note that border-image doesn't apply to internal table elements when ‘border-collapse’ is ‘collapse’: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image-source

Answer (score 2):

You have to separate the table border like this:

```
.table-bordered  {
    border-collapse:separate;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2y3xqq0q/5/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders

Answer (score 2):

What about forgetting about styling the table and wrap elements in divs instead and then styling the divs like the snippet below. Then just tweak it with something like `table td:not:(:last-of-type), table th:not(:last-of-type)` and `table tr:not(:last-of-type)` to remove the double borders that appear by setting specific border sides to appear

```css
.table-bordered div {
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 27px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 fill repeat;
}
.table-bordered * {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-bordered" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>Foo</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Bar</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Lols</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>something here</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>whatever</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>6,0% / 12% wag.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome, hopefully you can figure it out, if not with my solution, with another

Answer (score 1):

Your code is conflicting with bootstrap... try simplifying.

Here's an example without bootstrap and without that overly specific CSS on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ao4uays/) - once you know that works, you can start building up the complexity...

Bear in mind you may need to override certain Bootstrap CSS defaults, such as `border-collapse` etc. Also if those rules have higher CSS specificity than yours, they will take precedence over your rules.

Border image browser support can be found [here](http://caniuse.com#search=border-image).

Comment: Thanks. But why when I'm trying to collapse borders, images disappear like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ao4uays/1/)?

Answer (score 1):

`Bootstrap.css` definitions interfere with your css definition. In jsfiddle, when i remove `bootstrap.css` from external resources, everything works correctly.